# Property of Riemann zeta with function of representation of a number n

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

In the study of the properties of Rieamann zeta I encounterd the following:

Being $f_{k}(n)$ a multiplicative function as the number of representation of n as a product of k factor each greater than the unity when n>1 the order of the factor being essential. Then

$A:= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{f_{k}(n)}{n^s} = {(\zeta(s)-1)}^{k}$ for $\sigma >1$

the book also remind the theorem

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^s} = \prod (1 + \frac{f(p)}{p^s} + \frac{f(p^2)}{p^{2s}} + \cdots)$

Does some one can deduce A?

Comment: I don't understand "Does some understand A?" but I think A is well-known and probably an exercise in several intro Number Theory texts.

Comment: The book say "Clearly is ...", so I suppose it's logic

Comment: What book, please?

Comment: The Theory of the Rieamann zeta function, TitchMarsh

Comment: The theorem you refer to should have $p^s, p^{2s}, \ldots$ in the denominators, not $p, p^2, \ldots$

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article [Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series) states:

> Dirichlet series can be used as generating series for counting weighted sets of objects with respect to a weight which is combined multiplicatively when taking Cartesian products.

The primary example is the Riemann zeta function $\,\zeta(s)\,$ where each positive
integer has the same weight $1$. If we exclude the integer $1$, the generating series
is now $\,\zeta(s)-1.\,$ If we now multiply this generating series by
itself $\,k\,$ times, then we are counting the number of representation of $\,n\,$
as a product of $\,k\,$ factors each greater than the unity. Each series factor of
$\,\zeta(s)-1\,$ contributes one integer to the ordered integer factorization.

Comment: And the OP's function $f_k(n) = \sum_{m \in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 2}^k, n = \prod_j m_j} 1$ is not multiplicative as $f_k(1)=0, f_2(2) = f_2(3)=0$, $ f_k(6) = 2$

Comment: @reuns Thanks for that helpful comment!

Comment: No the $f_k(n)$ are not multiplicative because $m_j=1$ is forbidden in $n = \prod_j m_j$. The multiplicativity is for $\zeta(s)^k$ and the way $(\zeta(s)-1)^k$ fails to be mutiplicative is encoded in  $(\zeta(s)-1)^k = \sum_l {k \choose l} \zeta(s)^l (-1)^{k-l}$

Comment: I have shown in that generalized sense it is not true neither

Comment: @reuns Thanks for that helpful comment!  I forgot to mention that the the two products are required to be equal only when they are both non-zero.

Comment: Come on $f_2(n ) = \tau(n)-2$. That $f_2(ab)f_2(c)=f_2(a)f_2(bc)$ works only if $a,b$ have the same factorization type

Comment: @reuns Thanks for that **VERY** helpful comment!! I have deleted the NOTE. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think is easy to see if

$\zeta(s) -1 = \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} +\frac{1}{4^s} + \cdots$

therefore

$(\zeta(s) -1)^k = (\frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} + \cdots)_1 \cdots  (\frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} + \cdots)_k $

then each f_{n} is the number of rapresentation of products of a number n.